# How to get browser navigator (back and forward button) button handling for JavaScript (like jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I need get browser navigator handling example. I'm using example:
Imagine for many tab opener.

1. open new tab and switch to main tab opener page and create new tab.
2. close first opened tab.
3. click browser navigator back button. Focus last tab. Re-click back, focus main tab opener, re-click back stay main tab and history back disable, because I closed first tab. Imagine many probability. For example: I have 6 tabs and I closed 4th tab, and back or forward and pass to tab 4 if forward button clicked then go tab 5 if press back focus tab 3.

Comment: Are you talking about browser tabs or html tabs that you created?

Comment: html tabs. i'm creating tabs to jquery. and i using jquery history plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another jQuery plugin which might help: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)

Look at the example [here](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/tabs/).

It works with tabs and the back and forward buttons.